# What is the right order?

Tags: logic

The proof below has been scrambled. Please put it back in the correct order.

**Claim:** For all $n ≥ 9$, if $n$ is a perfect square, then $n-1$ is not prime.

1. Since $(n-1)$ is the product of 2 integers greater than 1, we know $(n-1)$ is not prime.
2. Since $m ≥ 3$, it follows that $m-1 ≥ 2$ and $m+1 ≥ 4$.
3. Let $n$ be a perfect square such that $n ≥ 9$.
4. This means that $n-1 = m^2-1 = (m-1)(m+1)$.
5. There is an integer $m ≥ 3$ such that $n=m^2$.

Comment: Have you figured out anything about the order, like, for example, which sentence should come first, or which should come last, or that one particular sentence must precede another in order for the latter to make sense?

Comment: What are your own thoughts? E.g., which line gives the conlusion and should be last? Which line reiterates the premise and should be first? Which lines use a variable and therefore cannot come before the introduction f that variable?

Comment: I thought the order would be 3, 1, 4, 5, 2. Just wanted to check to see if that is correct

Comment: That order is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

Sentence (1) concludes that "we know that $n-1$ is prime", which is in fact the concludion of the claim we want to proof. Thus it is a safe bet that (1) is the *last* sentence of the proof.

Sentence (2) starts "Since $m\ge 3$ ...", so it cannot come too early in the proof: For one, the sentence uses a variable $m$ that has not been introduced. Moreover, it uses a property that $m$ has as reason. So before (2) there must (somewhere) come a senetnce that introduces $m$ and (possibly another that) shows that $m\ge 3$. Both is handled in one sentence, namely (5).

Sentence (3) mkes use of nothing. Instead it introduces a variable $n$ with cerein propeties that match the premise of th eclaim., It is therefore a sfae bet that this is the first sentence of the proof.

Sentence (4) uses $m$ again, so it must come after the introduction of $m$.

This already rules out a lot and leaves only few possible orders. Why not write them down and verify if the argument is compelling? Always look out and check that no "Because of $A$ we know $B$" comes before $A$ has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

.3. Let n be a perfect square such that n≥9.

.5. There is an integer m≥3 such    that n=m2.

.2. Since m≥3, it follows that m−1≥2 and m+1≥4.

.4. This means    that n−1=m2−1=(m−1)(m+1).

.1. Since (n−1) is the product of 2 integers    greater than 1, we know (n−1) is not prime

qed

I figured this out by working out which was the last line of the proof (the one that established the claim (1.). Then I looked for the simplest assertion that could be made that would not rely on some prior assertion (a let statement is a giveaway here) -- the first statement. This left 3 statements to put in order. When you look at it that way, there is only one combination that gets you from the first statement(3) to the last (1).

Comment: Side note -- it occurs to me that this is maybe a homework question -- is it poor form to give the answer like this? Apologies if it is. I'm new to this SE...

Comment: I really doubt it is one.